# write image in external directory android

Tags: android, file-handling

How to write image in phone directory. Directory is created but i could not write image in this folder. Here is my code .please check if i am doing something wrong thanks in advance.

```
           Bitmap bitmap;
          String directory = new_path; // I am getting path here of image like sdcard/0/emulated/image.jpg
           String folder_name = "abc"

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(directory);

            iv_6.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // image displayed here but not saving in directory.

            try {

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator +folder_name);
                f.mkdirs();

                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, fo);
                fo.close();

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: you need to add file name with extention after folder name.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void savePng(Bitmap bitmap, String filePath) {
    try {
        File temp = new File(filePath);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(temp + ".png");
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but i am not getting image in phone directory

Comment: can you please post logcat